# Misbehaving Asp.net MVC helper methods (ie: Html.TextBox() and Html.Hidden())

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've been trying to debug an issue and I pinned pointed it down to this scenario:

When the statement Html.TextBox("ID", "What the heck..") is executed, I expect it to render:

```
<input id="ID" name="ID" type="text" value="What the heck.." />
```

But I get a Guid as its TextBox value such as so:

```
<input id="ID" name="ID" type="text" value="2e369d2c-071d-4733-8382-cc9e77d0b912" />
```

Why is Asp.net MVC outputting Guids? I'm not overriding asp.net mvc's framework methods. Please refer to the screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

**Update:**
Here's another screenshot using Html.Hidden() instead of Html.TextBox(). I couldn't use Html.HiddenFor() directly into the Watch window because HiddenFor() uses lambdas.

[image]

@Eric Petroelje and @TLS: You two are correct. TextBox() and Hidden() is retrieving ID's value from the POST variables and not from the current Model or the function's value parameter. Though, I've expected different from HiddenFor() and TextBoxFor(). I expected it to get its value from the POST'ed variables only if it cant get it from the current Model. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your screenshot only shows how you are using the `Html.HiddenFor` method, but your discussion talks about the `Html.Textbox` method.  Can you provide an example of how you are using `Html.Textbox` in your code?

Comment: @TLS - Look at the watch window.

Comment: @Mystere - Ah, okay.  Now I see what he's talking about.  The resizing of the screenshot does make it difficult to see all of the bits.

Comment: Thanks for your edits and clarification.  I think @EricP has the right answer, so his should probably be the accepted one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have a POST variable named `ID` that is a GUID?  If that's the case, the HTML Helper method will use that POST value.  If no POST value is present, it will fall back to the value in the model.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that `Html.TextBox("ID", "What the heck..")` is expected to output the attribute values that you give in your first example; however, if you are using the `Html.TextboxFor` method, then you're using a MVC Helper that dynamically loads the *value* of the `ID` property and places that into the `value` attribute in the HTML.  When you use the `Html.TextboxFor` method, your second example is the expected HTML output if your `ID` property is a Guid.